How do proponents of the Marcion hypothesis explain the similarities between the Gospel of Luke and Acts?
How do proponents of the theory that the Gospel of Luke is based on Marcion's Gospel explain the similarities with the Book of Acts? The scholarly consensus is that all the similarities show that they share the same author. Do proponents deny or accept that the Gospel of Luke and Acts were written by the same author? Having the same authorship seems like a very strong challenge to the theory. Unless Marcion had his own version of Acts also, but as far as I know I've never heard anyone mention that.

I think this belongs on ChristiantySE.
